# How to configure PATH in cron, so that it will be set for all crons?

Tags: linux, cron, shell

I have a problem where scripts called by cron have very short, safe, path: /usr/bin:/bin

I know, that I can:

1. Change scripts to use better path
2. in user crontab add PATH=... configuration

But I'd like to be able to tell crond that on this system all crons should be called with PATH=...

I tried putting it in /etc/crontab:

```
=# grep PATH /etc/crontab 
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

And then, for tests, I wrote:

```
=# cat /etc/cron.d/test 
* * * * *  test echo "$( date ) - ${PATH}" >> /tmp/test.cron.log
```

But logged path is still "/usr/bin:/bin"

I did restart crond, and even rebooted, just in case, but it doesn't seem to help. What am I missing? Or is it impossible?

Comment: No implementation of `cron` that I have examined has a standard configuration mechanism whereby you can define environmental variables such as `PATH` which then will be included in each crontab file automatically.

Comment: OK, Thanks. Knowing that there is no solution is also a solution :)